# Взаимодействие между двумя и более ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа. Прошу помочь мне в моем спаггети-коде и разложить все по полочкам. Суть следующая:
Есть окно, в этом окне есть два контрола - `Menu` и `Frame`. Также имеется страница `Page`, которая указана в `Frame`.
Меню представляет из себя выбор категорий, а страница, которая отображается в Frame, представляет из себя изделия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак. У окна есть свой VM - `WindowViewModel`. В этом VM есть вложенное VM - `MenuViewModel`, которое является View Model'ом моего меню. У этого `MenuViewModel` есть открытое свойство:

```
Category selectedMenuItem;
public Category SelectedMenuItem
{
    get => selectedMenuItem;
    set { Set( ref selectedMenuItem, value ); }
}
```

которое представлет из себя выбранный пункт меню, и отражается на определенную категорию `Category`.
До этого момент должно быть все понятно. Теперь страница:

Каждая страница наследуется вот от такого класса( не буду весь класс пилить сюда, оставлю только самое основное):

```
public class BasePage<VM> : Page where VM : BaseViewModel, new()
{
    VM viewModel;
    public VM ViewModel
    {
        get {  return viewModel; }
        set
        {
            if( viewModel == value )
                return;

            viewModel = value;
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }

    public BasePage()
    {
        ViewModel = new VM();
    }
}
```

Итого мы имеем вот такую страницу, для отображения изделий:

```
public partial class ProductListPage : BasePage<ProductListViewModel>
{
    public ProductListPage() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

`ProductListViewModel` - это VM для страницы отображения изделий. Это большой класс, в котором написаны тонкости вывода изделий, поэтому не очень хочется приводить его здесь. Единственное что скажу, это то, что в конструкторе этого VM идет запрос у репозитория на получение всех изделий из БД, чтобы при первом старте страницы, отображались все товары, всех категорий.

А теперь собственно вопрос. Как правильно сделать взаимодействие между двумя VM'ами - `MenuViewModel` и `ProductListViewModel`. После изменения текущего пункта меню, в `MenuViewModel` срабатывает команда, в обработчике этой команды обновляется свойство `SelectedMenuItem`. Как теперь известить `ProductListViewModel` о том, что нужно отфильтровать список изделий?
Меня не интересуют кривые решения этой проблемы. Я и сам могу это реализовать. Мне бы хотелось услышать изящные решения, которые я, возможно, буду применять в будущем. Спасибо

Comment: По сути, вопрос состоит в том, как организовать взаимодействие между двумя объектами. MVVM здесь ведь не при чём?

Comment: для организации сообщения не связанных между собой VM обычно используют один из двух подходов: либо через посредническую VM (например, родительскую), либо через шину сообщений.

Comment: `Меня не интересуют кривые решения этой проблемы. Я и сам могу это реализовать. Мне бы хотелось услышать изящные решения, которые я, возможно, буду применять в будущем.` - ничего такая заявочка! Это можно интерпретировать таким образом: помогите мне с решением проблемы, а я уже сам решу отблагодарить вас или нет в зависимости от желания моей левой пятки. Вы, случайно, не невеста на выданье?

Comment: @Bulson не совсем понятно что вас возмущает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, попробую ответить на этот вопрос в меру своего понимания.

Для взаимодействия VM-объектов между собой они должны быть связаны. Таким образом, между объектами должна существовать *зависимость*.

Для того, чтобы установить зависимость между объектами, есть много путей. Либо один из группы объектов (обычно «родительский») берёт на себя ответственность по созданию и настройке объектов-потомков, либо (если настройки и связи становятся слишком сложны, чтобы быть ответственностью одного VM-объекта) эта ответственность делегируется «внешнему», управляющему объекту, чьё единственное задание — связать VM-объекты между собой правильным образом.

Для того, чтобы один подобъект «узнал» о другом, я бы использовал традиционные средства «ручного» внедрения зависимостей: конструктор с нужными параметрами, на крайний случай — открытые для записи свойства. Полновесное внедрение зависимостей в моей практике использовать для простой цели связи VM-объектов не приходилось, и было практически всегда излишним.

---

Для вашего случая я бы связал `MenuViewModel` (или, возможно, лишь `SelectedMenuItem`) с `ProductListPage`, чтобы она могла сама следить за изменением `SelectedMenuItem`'а и надлежащим образом реагировать.

---

Важное замечание. Для того, чтобы возможно было связывание VM (да и просто в соответствии с паттерном MVVM, если вы его придержтваетесь), у вас VM-объекты наподобие `ProductListViewModel` не должны конструироваться во View, и должны иметь конструктор с параметрами. `DataContext` для окна должен устанавливаться самой программой, а `DataContext` для внутренних контролов должен в большинстве случаев устанавливаться через привязку к свойствам `DataContext`'а охватывающих контролов.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Bretbas: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло.